# What is the best hat available?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I'm pretty sure this Mr. Peanut Monopoly McDuck hat is the best hat going, don't you agree? Who else is proud of their hat?

[image: Mr. Peanut Monopoly McDuck]

Comment: you're correct <@:)

Answer (score 9):

I think mine is rather fetching, even if my view is a little obscured!

[image]

Comment: You can reposition it so your view isn't obscured :) In your "hat rack" popup, you can drag it around before clicking "Wear hat".

Comment: Got it - thanks!

Comment: What about if your head is really tiny? Can I resize it? (The hat that is, not my head)

Answer (score 7):

I think mine's a better fit

[image]

Comment: I needed a head on shot to wear that one! I like my Monacle though :)

Answer (score 7):

I kind of like *SaaSy* the Snowman.

[image: SaaSy the Snowman]

Answer (score 6):

Well now I've got the Chuck Yeager secret hat! Not sure what for, but I'm happy to go bust the sound barrier. It's amazing what you can learn from the trivia game on Qantas flights ;)[image: Chuck Yeager!]

Comment: You've got the "Right Stuff". ;-)

Comment: Just earned this hat. I've been coveting it...

Answer (score 6):

It's not really in the spirit of the winter bash, but inspecting browser elements [reveals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cdWL.png):

[image: All the summer bash hats]

I'd really like to steal someone's checkmark so I can legitimately get [a pirate hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/marauder), even if it is to big for my tiny avatar head.

Answer (score 6):

Sits just perfectly!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Does [this hat](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/320/user320)  make my butt look big?

[ghost http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013/img/1389235402-128.png?2](http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013/img/1389235402-128.png?2)

Answer (score 5):

I just LOVE my `russian power` helmet!

[image]

Comment: Fits perfectly! :-)

Answer (score 5):

I also have a `secret hat` for what I got it i don't knw and `Boater hat` and one for `Frosty the Snowman`  bt I feel very excited and proud after wear it all one by one and also try to get more. [image] [image] [image]

Comment: the secret hat is for being FAST ;) the guy broke the sound barrier

Answer (score 4):

My parents always wanted me to be a judge and I always wanted to be a technology geek. This is probably as close as I'll be to becoming a judge.

Thank you Stack Exchange for fulfilling my parents dreams :)

[image: Presenting Gaurav Kheterpal - The Judge!]

Comment: I'm already starting to miss my collection of hats :(

Comment: Fits perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

love the chuck yeager hat, but I'ma gonna go with the orange triangle of awesome.